# How to disable touchpad mouse movement in Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, touchpad, thinkpad

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad T440p as you can see link image below.. I have a problem with the touchpad, it caused the mouse to go crazy on its own. I want to disable certain functionality from the touchpad not the whole touchpad. In this model of ThinkPad the touchpad is used to move the mouse AND to click on things. The goal is to disable the mouse movement ONLY from the touchpad and use it just for clicks(right and left click). To move the mouse I will be using the pointing stick (red dot on the keyboard)

OS: Fedora 33

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61PAPjIw2YL._AC_SL1181_.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your touchpad has a hardware device that communicates with the motherboard as a whole. Some touchpads communicate under i2c standards others under usb standards.

If you disable the driver, you disable the whole thing. Since the comms happens serially, there's no hardware solution to separate touch signals from button signals either.

If your device is not behaving properly, very likely you have the wrong driver installed for your device.

Comment: how can I identify the driver I'm using and see if it is correct? In some other forum somebody said to use synaptics.conf to isolate the functionality.. would that help?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Most modern desktop environments use libinput directly. Gnome for example will allow you to adjust that setting as shown here, 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w4d0iVt0VUmrHNsI2eGN-Wa1Jqusk3wF/view
but I wasn't able to completely disable the touch movement.

Comment: yea same thing with me. it will disable the touchpad completely ...

Comment: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/t440-support.html
check on this, this might be your issue